# discord.py "sub help command"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if it's possible to make a somewhat "sub help command" basically if I were to do ;help mute it would show how to use the mute command and so on for each command. Kinda like dyno how you can do ?help (command name) and it shows you the usage of the command. I have my own help command already finished but I was thinking about adding to it so if someone did ;help commandname it would show them the usage such as arguments I tried at the bottom but I don't think that will work. If you know how please let me know

```
@client.hybrid_command(name = "help", with_app_command=True, description="Get a list of commands")
@commands.guild_only()
async def help(ctx, arg = None):
    pages = 3
    cur_page = 1
    roleplayembed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Roleplay Commands")
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Cuddle", value="Cuddle a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Hug", value="Hug a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Kiss", value="Kiss a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Slap", value="Slap a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Pat", value="Pat a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.set_footer(text=f"Page {cur_page+1} of {pages}")
    roleplayembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    basicembed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Basic Commands")
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Waifu", value="Posts a random AI Generated Image of a waifu",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}8ball", value="Works as an 8 ball",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Ara", value="Gives you a random ara ara from Kurumi Tokisaki",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Wikipedia", value="Search something up on the wiki",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Userinfo", value="Look up info about a user",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Ask", value="Ask the bot a question",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Askwhy", value="Ask the boy a question beginning with 'why'",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Avatar", value="Get a user's avatar or your own avatar",inline=False)
    basicembed.set_footer(text=f"Page {cur_page} of {pages}")
    basicembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    moderationembed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Moderation Commands")
    moderationembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Kick", value="Kick a member",inline=False)
    moderationembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Ban", value="Ban a member",inline=False)
    moderationembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Slowmode", value="Set the slowmode of a channel",inline=False)
    moderationembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Purge", value="Purge an amount of messages in a channel",inline=False)
    moderationembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Mute", value="Mute a member for a time and reason",inline=False)
    moderationembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Unmute", value="Unmute a member for a time and reason",inline=False)
    moderationembed.set_footer(text=f"Page {cur_page+2} of {pages}")
    moderationembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    contents = [basicembed, roleplayembed, moderationembed]
    if arg == None:
        message = await ctx.send(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
        

        await message.add_reaction("◀️")
        await message.add_reaction("▶️")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
       
        while True:

            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️":
                    cur_page += 1
                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️": 
                    cur_page -= 1
                if cur_page > pages: #check if forward on last page
                    cur_page = 1 
                elif cur_page < 1: #check if back on first page
                    cur_page = pages 
                await message.edit(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.delete()
                break
    if arg.lower() == client.command_name:
        await ctx.reply(f"{client.command_prefix}{client.command_name}{client.command_argument}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.

When you're using slash commands (which you are currently not,) there is a really elegant way to do this in the form of SlashCommandGroups. This would get the commands as [command name] help instead, but I don't think that is a downside.

This would work like this, an example I thought of was blocking:

```py
class Block(discord.ext.commands.Cog):
    block = SlashCommandGroup("block")

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @block.command(name="add")
    async def add(args):
        # Something here

    @block.command(name="remove")
    async def remove(args):
        # Something here

    @block.command(name="help")
    async def help(args):
        # Get help message for this command
```

This would expose the commands `block add [args]`, `block remove [args]` and `block help` each of which calls their own sub-command in the cog, and I think this is the cleanest way to get a consistent help system.

You can add this cog to your bot with `bot.add_cog(Block(bot))` somewhere in your code. Specifically, I'd look into [extensions](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/extensions.html)

---

Then, for what you want to do, You're not using slash commands, so you don't need to provide autocomplete. If you want to, you can do something really hacky, using this helper function, which will work as long as you have the function in your current scope:

```py
def help(function_name):
    return globals()[function_name].__doc__
```

Now, you can define the help of every function individually using [docstrings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-docstrings/), and the help command will simply get those doc strings and presumably do something with it.

---

The way Dyno would do it is more complex, using slash commands again, but really similar to the first version. You simply add a slash command group again, but this time it is for helping specifically. I personally don't like this as much, as I think the code is a lot less clean, but if you really want the `help [function]` syntax instead of `[function] help`, this is how to do that:

```py
class Help(discord.ext.commands.Cog):
    help = SlashCommandGroup("help")

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @help.command(name="block")
    async def block(args):
        # Send the user the help response for blocking

    @help.command(name="ask")
    async def ask(args):
        # Send the user the help response for asking
```

I hope that helps! :-)